# Count occurrences of complex types in a XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd, metrics

Currently, I am facing a very big XSD file that consist of more than 20000 lines of code. The top level XSD file makes use of includes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:okstra="http://schema.okstra.de/2016/okstra" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schema.okstra.de/2016/okstra" version="2.016.0">
  <include schemaLocation="Datentypen.xsd"/>
  <include schemaLocation="S_Administration.xsd"/>
  <include schemaLocation="S_Allgemeine_Geometrieobjekte.xsd"/>
  <include schemaLocation="S_Allgemeine_Mengenberechnung.xsd"/>
  <include schemaLocation="S_Allgemeine_Objekte.xsd"/>
```

I want to know how many complex types are included in the XML schema. Furthermore, I am interested in the maximum, minimum and average number of attributes per complex type. Also im interested in inheritance trees. I want to know the minimum, maximum and averange depth of the inheritance tree of a complex type.

Is there a tool that can calculate this software metric values?

Or is there a quick hack (using a programming language such as Python, C#, Java, whatever) to get this numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a tooling perspective, [QTAssistant](https://www.paschidev.com) (I am associated with it) has a component, named [Query for XSD Analysis](https://www.paschidev.com/whitepapers/query-xsd-getting-started.aspx), which should help you with what you've described. In fact, there's a how-to paper which deals exactly with your subject: [XSD Complexity Analysis](https://www.paschidev.com/whitepapers/qxsd-xsd-complexity-analysis.aspx).

The good thing: you can build any possible report, since the tool is based on a model that captures all facets of the XSD 1.0 language and its patterns, which in turn, through SQL, can be further massaged and queried for whatever stats, and patterns you may think of. It is being used extensively in organizations which (so far) meet the following criteria: deal frequently with large models expressed using XSD, and require adherence to XSD design guidelines defined in-house or by industry groups.

The caveat: you need to know SQL; it is a variety of Transact-SQL (we provide a reference [here](https://www.paschidev.com/dataset-sql.aspx)) with some extensions such as RegEx support (.NET's variety), spell checking (not so sure about German, but for sure there's a way to support it), etc. It can handle really large XSDs (20,000 is nothing, really, compared with what I've dealt with) , but then you may need more modern hardware.

For e.g., if you want to know the number of complex types:

```
SELECT count(*) from XSComplexType
```

If you want to know metrics regarding number of attributes, I would have to ask: the PSVI set (The collection of all the attributes from this complex type and its base types) or just those defined at the complex type level (from an authoring perspective)?

For all uses:

```
Select count(*) As [Total Attributes],
  XSComplexType.LocalName,
  XSComplexType.Namespace
From XSComplexTypeAttributeUses
  Inner Join XSComplexType
    On XSComplexType.RowId = XSComplexTypeAttributeUses.XSComplexTypeRowId
Group By XSComplexType.LocalName,
  XSComplexType.Namespace
```

Anyway, for more complicated queries (since the model is highly normalized), you could use the help of the built in model browser and query builder:

[image: QTAssistant QXSD screenshot]

Based on the amount of work poured into this, I would think that XSD complexity analysis may not be that simple to achieve - of course, if one wants to provide a user with a generic solution to schema analysis and reporting.

If I would have to hack it and only for the numbers you've asked, I would choose .NET's API for processing XSDs.

Start with a loaded and compiled [XmlSchemaSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset(v=vs.110).aspx).

To count the number of complex types: loop through [XmlSchemaSet.GlobalTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset.globaltypes(v=vs.110).aspx).Values and count all instances of [XmlSchemaComplexType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemacomplextype(v=vs.110).aspx). It requires more work if your schema uses the chameleon pattern.

To count the number of attributes per complex type: start with [XmlSchemaComplexType.AttributeUses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemacomplextype.attributeuses(v=vs.110).aspx). Keep track of the numbers to extract the stats you need (min/max/avg). If you want to count the attributes defined for each type, you have more work since you have to look at the Attributes property which, unlike AttributeUses, may contain references to attribute groups. And consider the use=prohibited scenario (i.e, in an inheritance scenario, that should reduce the number of attributes, etc.)

For inheritance trees, for each type you're interested in, follow the PSVI [BaseXmlSchemaType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschematype.basexmlschematype(v=vs.110).aspx) property - make sure that you're not dealing with redefines, in which case you have to use special logic there. As you traverse the base types (stop when the base type name is in the http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema namespace), keep track of the depth, and so calculate the average depth.

You could also write it in Java, using [Apache's XSOM library](https://ws.apache.org/xmlschema/). I prefer .NET's as personally I find it better suited for "hack" jobs. With Python, you still can, if you process it like XML. I could write it even using XSLT or XQuery. Still, I would choose a specialized XSD processor, to take advantage of validation and PSVI.